# Authenticating external users on SQL Server Reporting Service

Tags: windows, reporting-services, windows-server-2008

My test app always asks for sign to view report. Test does not behave as production version which allows report viewing for each new user that is granted with VPN access. I can't figure out what setting is different on two systems that should let users from outside domain use reporting.

This is the problem:

If for example I set new password for BUILTIN\Administrator user, on production server I start getting prompted for credentials, and if I set old password SSRS will not prompt to sign in anymore.

My question is:

How can I modify user password so that SSRS service still work the same way?

Or maybe, how can I make my test behave as production does?